# Seeking two prayers from Rig Veda

Tags: rig-veda

I would need two prayers from Rig Veda in romanized Sanskrit for chanting, does someone know where to find them?

tvam trata tarane chetyo bhuh pita mata sadamin manushanam

May you be our saviour, protector, father and mother of mortals forever.

brhaspatirnah pari paatu pashchaadutottarasmaadadharaadaghaayoh

Brihaspati protect us from the rear and from above and below from harm.

Comment: You can use some tools online for transliteration. Our site doesn't provide transliteration for the mantras. Moreover, these mantras are to be chanted after knowing how to spell and pronounce them. So, it is better you seek a pundit who can chant for you. There are many rules before chanting mantras from Vedas.

Comment: You should ask for pronunciation instead of asking romanized Sanskrit. Reading Vedas in Romanized Sanskrit is not the right way and it will lead to bad effects if chanted wrong. They have specific swara and rules to chant. Please see an expert in it.

Answer (score 3):

You can find or search verses of Rigveda from [here](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/rigveda/e-text.htm)

RV VI.1.5:

> त्वां वर्धन्ति क्षितयः पृथिव्यां त्वां राय उभयासो जनानाम्।
>   त्वं त्राता तरणे चेत्यो भूः पिता माता सदमिन्मानुषाणाम्॥
>
> tvā́ṃ vardhanti kṣitáyaḥ pṛthivyā́ṃ tvā́ṃ rā́ya ubháyāso jánānām |
>
> tváṃ trātā́ taraṇe cétyo bhūḥ pitā́ mātā́ sádam ín mā́nuṣāṇām ||

RV.X.44.11:

> बृहस्पतिर्नः परि पातु पश्चादुतोत्तरस्मादधरादघायोः।
>   इन्द्रः पुरस्तादुत मध्यतो नः सखा सखिभ्यो वरिवः कृणोतु॥ १०.०४४.११
>
> bṛ́haspátir naḥ pári pātu pašcā́d utóttarasmād ádharād aghāyóḥ |
>
> índraḥ purástād utá madhyató naḥ sákhā sákhibhyo várivaḥ kṛṇotu॥

Comment: Sanskrit language questions are off-topic for our site. It includes transliteration too. It doesn't require our site at all. Do not answer off-topic questions. Moreover, mantra pronunciation is different and very specific and can't be learnt by IAST script. It's done differently and learnt from an expert.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma: Thanks for the tip. However, there is no basis for claiming "Sanskrit language questions are off-topic for our site". He is asking about verses  from the Rig Veda arguably the most relevant question on Hinduism one could ask. It is arbitrary to reject such questions. We either confirm that it is indeed from the Rig Veda or that the claim is false. An exact diacritically annotated transliteration is critical in representing a verse from Sanskrit, Telugu or Tamil. Nobody has the right to deny answers to legitimate  questions by dictating how the answer shall be used.

Comment: You should read [Should we close questions related to Sanskrit language and grammar as off-topic?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/748/5212). When one says, it is off-topic, the basis is faq or the help center. Check them. The question is transliteration. For that the site is not required. Some online tool is enough. Such questions only attract low quality questions. Please read [help] and [meta-tag:faq]. It is a unwritten rule that off-topic questions should not be answered. It is not dictation. It is general etiquette on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma:  This one is not among them. On your statement "Such questions only attract low quality questions", if they do then this site has people who hav eno knowledge of Sanskrit but proffer seemingly authoritative answers to gullible readers which is the case actually. This forum is rife with many questions, not off-topic per your criteria, with highly incorrect answers  and with obviously wrong translations of quoted Sanskrit verses. That they stay without ever being corrected is alarming. Most answers are based on beliefs and are not true in the scholarly sense. Need a shift of focus!

Comment: @Pandya: I had to add the version with accent marks. The DevnagarI version shall also have the accent marks.

Comment: There is no own criteria in closing or reopening questions. You need to understand Stack Exchange model of  moderation. For that please [help]. Policies are decided after discussions on Meta. If transliteration of Shloka, Sanskrit verses are allowed, there can be 1k questions which doesn't require any expertise to answer. Just copy paste from an online tool is enough for that. Sanskrit != Hinduism.  If you find wrong answers or false answers, please downvote and write answers based on scholarly sense. You are welcome to do that instead of saying incorrect answers are posted. Focus on that!